# Android Qr Code scan automatically

Tags: android, qr-code, google-vision

i have implemented qr scan from camera but i have to capture the picture my self , what can i do to process i automatically without capturing it myself and here is my code

```
BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    if (!detector.isOperational()) {
        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "Could not set up the detector!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
public void Scan(View view) {
    Permissions permissions = new Permissions(ScanActivity.this);
    permissions.showCameraStatePermission();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if (detector.isOperational() && bitmap != null) {
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
                Barcode code = barcodes.valueAt(0);
                Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, code.displayValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

Comment: thank you for your reply  ,but is there any way to develop it my self ??